# add google analityc to metro app

Tags: winjs

i am try installed google analityc to windows microsoft visual studio 8 for metro app, but i have the problem, when install i have the problem at below

PM> Install-Package w8ga
Successfully installed 'w8ga 2.3'.
Directory '' is not empty. Skipping...
Successfully uninstalled 'w8ga 2.3'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'DT.GoogleAnalytics.Metro'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package w8ga
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

any body can help me

thanks 
iwan

Answer (score 0):

"w8ga 2.3" is targeted for "Windows Store App" and for other project templates, package manager throws error.
You might try with Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Store App to get it working.